# How can I make a field which is generic field autowired with dynamic generate in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I defined some interfaces with generic, and I have some classes injected in Spring context as Beans, could I dynamic create a manager bean to manage them, and it could be autowired in fields without any Bean def code of this manager?

I have tried FactoryBean way to implement it, but not worked, it couldn't transmit generic class info and the FactoryBean bean couldn't transmit any changable arguments.

I have tried BeanFactory way to implement it, when I getBeansOfType, these objects created without autowired, not worked...

Now I have a finally method which I think it's not very smart that is using ImportBeanDefinitionRegistrar and ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner to scan all classes, then insert the manager's beanDefinition.

I'll be very appreciate if you supply any method, Thank you very much !

I want to implement it like this:

```java
public interface Strategy<E extends BaseEnum>
{
    public E getType();
}

public interface LoginStrategy extends Strategy<LoginType>
{
    public LoginStrategy getType();
}

@Strategy
public class ALoginStrategy implements LoginStrategy 
{
    public getType()
    {
         return LoginType.OTP;
    }
}

@Strategy
public class BLoginStrategy implements LoginStrategy 
{
    @Autowired
    private UserMapper;

    public getType()
    {
         return LoginType.PASSWORD;
    }
}
```

```java
public LoginServiceImpl implements LoginService
{
    @Autowired
    private StrategyManage<LoginType, LoginStrategy> strategyManager;
}
```

I want the strategyManager in LoginServiceImpl which is marked Autowired could be auto generated.

I also have a other question. It may be easier to explain what I want.

I have a model convertor implements a ModelConvertor interface, TL is lowerModel's class, TU is upperModel's class.

now there is a bean include code like this:

```java
@Autowired
private ModelConvertor<UserPO, UserDO> userConvertor;
```

normally Spring frame would throw a Exception with a "no such bean" message, so I want to make this field could auto inject a value like this:

```java
@Autowired
private ModelConvertor<UserPO, UserDO> userConvertor[ = new DefaultModelConvertor(UserPO.class, UserDO.class)];
```

How can I do to solve these problems, thanks a lot again!

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this problem, scan specific packages and dynamic generate beans to put on context.